# How to add select2 js in wordpress admin side theme options

Tags: wordpress, admin, jquery-select2, media

I have added Select2 js to provide search capabilities in my wordpress theme setting drop down options to add search -> http://nimb.ws/1QW6id

I have added the following code to my admin options file:

```
<?php if(is_admin()) { ?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.option-tree-ui-select').select2();
});
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

On the admin side this works, but the code conflicts with the admin side media menu. The media menu continuously loads and does not allow the uploading of new images. When I remove the new code, the media functionality begins to work appropriately.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please list the errors you are receiving.

Comment: No any errors display in firebug. But admin side media menu continue show loading -> http://nimb.ws/CIfdo6

Comment: Your links are directing to insecure websites.  Please use a different image provider if you're attempting to upload an image for review.

Comment: Please review this url https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1485315/k76iddr67qkzev0esnqv

Comment: Any update here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `wp_enqueue_script` function for including scripts. Also remove your jquery call. Use dependencies.

See an [example](https://gist.github.com/yanknudtskov/babd3f979e449015d2d82f1c83a719be)

Place this code in functions.php of your theme or in main plugin file:

```
function enqueue_select2_jquery() {
    wp_register_style( 'select2css', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.8/select2.css', false, '1.0', 'all' );
    wp_register_script( 'select2', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.4.8/select2.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'select2css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'select2' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_select2_jquery' );
```

This action will include select2 libraries and jquery. Third parameter of `wp_register_script` told WordPress that for this script working fine should be included jquery core. See more details on [developers portal](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). If set 3rd param to `array('jquery')` jquery core will be included before your select2 plugin automatically.

Than in your page, header, scrtip file (where you wanna) place JS with call select2 plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
      $('.option-tree-ui-select').select2();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where i can put this file. Can you please explain me more using my above code. Also in my wordpress admin side theme settings `jquery.min.js` not included. Without that select2 not working. So i have added `jquery.min.js` to. Thanks.

Comment: Edited my answer. See more details.

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.option-tree-ui-select').select2();
});
</script>`
Here display error in inspect element ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: perlace $ to jQuery

Comment: Ok and also inform me where i can add that last code ? I want to include that script in admin side theme options.

Comment: Where you need use select2 plugin.